# Failure to connect to Linux socket on RHEL6, No such file or directory

Tags: c, linux, sockets

The following code always fails to connect to a socket when running on RHEL6 (which is my target production system), but works properly on Ubuntu.

```
int client_connect(char * socketId) {
  int len;
  struct sockaddr_un remote;

  if (socketId == NULL) {
    printf("ERROR: No socket ID given to the simulator\n");
    return 1;
  }

  if ((sock = socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == -1) {
    printf("ERROR: The simulator failed to create a socket! %s\n", strerror(errno));
    return 1;
  }

  printf("[DEBUG] The socket ID is: %s\n", socketId);
  remote.sun_family = AF_UNIX;
  strcpy(remote.sun_path, socketId);
  len = strlen(remote.sun_path) + sizeof(remote.sun_family);
  if (connect(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&remote, len) == -1) {
    printf("ERROR: The simulator failed to connect to Origen's socket! %s\n", strerror(errno));
    return 1;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
[DEBUG] The socket ID is: /tmp/224414844153787363172.sock
ERROR: The simulator failed to connect to Origen's socket! No such file or directory
```

The socket definitely exists and the ID passed into this function is definitely correct.

I am at a loss as to what the problem could be, especially since it works on other systems.

Appreciate any thoughts or advice!

Comment: Why isn't `len = sizeof(remote)`? Note that [the pathname has to be NUL-terminated](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/unix.7.html), while [`strlen()` excludes the NUL terminator](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/unix.7.html). Might be worth checking that your `connect()` actually gets the full length of the pathname.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @chrisaycock. Don't know why sizeof(remote) wasn't used. This is my first time using sockets and I copied that from a tutorial, but I can confirm that it still passes/fails as before after making that change.

Comment: On what architecture and int size are you seeing the problem? Try `len = offsetof(struct sockaddr_un, sun_path)+strlen(remote.sun_path)+1`, which is recommended by the man page.

Comment: Hi @MarkPlotnick, both systems are 64-bit and 4-byte int size. Thanks for the suggestion, however the result is the same with that change.
I've made a little bit of progress by changing the path of the socket from /tmp to /home/myuserid, I now get the error as 'connection refused'.
I have no idea why though.